# Get Available Random Filename for Next Upload on Google Cloud Storage

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

Good day to everyone

I'm uploading every user-submitted file to google cloud storage, and i'm currently generating 20-character string on the backend that will be used as a new filename for that newly uploaded file on Google Cloud Storage.

But there is nevertheless a possibility i will generate filename that is already used on GCS. I'm uploading stuff on production and localhost, so i can't use database to check what filenames were already used.

How can i ask google for random N-character string that can be used as a identifier for the next uploaded file?

Our, can i upload file and get filename after, by sending data on request about the nature of filename i want to have?

Thanks in advance, guys and gals!
Wish you all the best!

Answer (score 0):

The possibility is likely lower than you think. If you use upper case letters A-Z, lower case letters a-z, and numbers 0-9, and you construct a completely random 20 character string, that's (26+26+10)<sup>20</sup> possibilities, or 7.04x10<sup>35</sup> possible combinations. In order to have even a 1 in a million chance of a collision, you would need to upload somewhere on the order of 3.7 trillion objects.

But perhaps they're not truly random strings, or users get to pick them, or you rely on some algorithm that might from time to time produce identical "random" strings. In that case, a good precaution would be to instruct GCS to only allow the upload if it would not overwrite an already-existing object. You can do this with the XML or JSON API by setting the "ifGenerationMatch" parameter to "0".